# Express Error when trying to add a file

Tags: node.js, express

I have

```
var users1 = require('./users');
```

when I am trying to compile a file with this line :
I am getting the Error:

```
undefined:2
    ∩┐╜tobi∩┐╜: {
    ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ∩┐╜
        at Object.parse (native)
        at Object..json (module.js:471:25)
        at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
        at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
        at require (module.js:375:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node\XXXXXXX)
        at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
        at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
```

I am really not getting what is the issuw with that line.
It is a file names users.jason with json bodies

the content of the user.json is :

```
{
    “tobi”: {
        “password”: “xxxxxx”
    }
}
```

should it be .json (or) json?

Comment: can you show us the content of the json file? Maybe the format isn't right or some characters cannot be read.

Comment: @zeMirco I have updated the question with the contents of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `users.js` file has those special characters. You may only use the following characters for identifiers, and i quote http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

> An identifier must start with $, _, or any character in the Unicode categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”, “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”, or “Letter number (Nl)”.

Have you tried redefining the `∩┐╜tobi∩┐╜` into something utf-8 like?

LATER EDIT:

The double quotes that you are using are wrong. Copy+paste and use these from now on: "